# Restore Keyboard Layout Icon and locale

Tags: gnome, icons, keyboard-layout

I'm an Ubuntu 12.04 user, using Gnome Classic (with no effects).
I don't know what I did, but lately instead of the keyboard layout with the locale (for example, IT, UK and so on) a strange "no access" symbol appears.
See the linked image.

ow can I restore the default keyboard icon and the language indicator?

[image]

Issuing

```
locale -a
```

in a terminal i get the following output:

```
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8 
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Comment: please share the output of `locale -a`.

Comment: Thanks @Samik I edited the question so to contain the output.

Comment: Can you go to `gnome-control-center` > `Keyboard Layout` > `Add`(+)> select layout?

Comment: Hi @Samik, yes I can

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question , thought your keyboard-indicator is disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually that symbol means a missing pixmap/image. I think either the keyboard icon image or the country-flags icons are missing. You can install `dconf-tool` with `sudo apt-get install dconf-tool`, open the `dconf-editor` then go to `org>gnome>libgnomekbd>indicator` and uncheck the `show-flags` option if it's checked. Log-out and log-in back again to see if the keyboard icon appears there.

Comment: Hi @Samik, I'll try this solution as soon as I'm in front to the computer with this issue and let you know if it worked

Comment: Hi @Samik, I have tried your solution. It worked in the sense that now instead of the ugly "forbidden" signal a fancy keyboard icon is displayed. What I can't manage to see though is the layout used. I have an UK keyboard, but since I'm Italian I switch frequently between the UK Standard (when I program) and the UK Extended (when I have to write in Italian). On my laptop when I switch keyboard I have "en" or "en2" displayed closed to the keyboard that tells me which layout I'm using. Can I restore that behaviour as well? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @LucaCerone The behaviour you want seems to be changed in new releases, the indiactor either use the country flags or the keyboard icon. But [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Ubuntu+Mono+Light?content=134483) you can download country flags which are actually images showing _two letter country codes_. Extract them in `/home/<user>/.icons/flags` or `/usr/share/pixmaps` and re-enable the `show-flags` using `dconf-editor`.

Comment: that package doesn't include the flags for English Uk.. I could create it just copying the file en.svg and renaming it into gb.svg. Doing that the indicator for the English Uk layout is shown correctly. I can't find the combination for the English UK international layout though.